# Safety Standards for Low Voltage Systems

Tags: mains, safety, isolation, low-voltage, cable-assemblies

I am looking for safety standards which could be applied to the piece of equipment desribed below.

Basically the piece of equipment is a housing which inherits a 24V 100Wh Battery (2x [SBS60](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1506592.pdf?_ga=2.199324333.2057265590.1522133408-1337038897.1501743580)) and a appropriate, off the shelf, Battery Charger. The used Battery Charger ([ABC2430](http://www.leab.eu/en/products/battery-chargers/24v/abc-chargers.html/)), has a standard AC power cord which in this case is cut to insert a mechnical switch aswell as a different connector which are both installed in the mentioned housing wall.

My question is, which safety standards could be relevant concerning the internal housing wiring of mains voltage carrying cables, insulation of mains voltage carrying parts inside the housing, earthing of the housing, distances to mains voltage carrying parts, etc. The housing can be opened without using a key or any tools.

So far i came up with EN60664, EN60335 and EN60950, but im not sure if i maybe missed one or there is something more suitable.

**Edit:** I am located in Austria but the equipment should be CE conform basically everywhere. The Box is used as a backup supply for radio communication equipment indoors as well as outdoors.

Comment: It might help to add your country. As you're referring to EN standards, I guess you're in the UK and you want a CE mark? Also, where will the equipment be used? If it's for use in a lab, for example, you might use EN61010.

Comment: EN55011, EN55022, EN60950.

Comment: If possible, look at the DoCs for similar products in the market, and see what standards they refer to

Answer (score 1):

Look at 60335-2-29 and at the low voltage directive (LVD).  Be sure to read the normative references page and follow those that apply.